# Use $in operator to match regex in mongoengine

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongoengine

Following the MongoDB documentation, you can use the *$in* operator with a regular expression like wise `db.inventory.find( { tags: { $in: [ /^be/, /^st/ ] } } )`. Is there a way to achieve the same result using **mongoengine**?

For example pass `{"tags__in": ["/^be/", "/^st/"]}` to my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is supported by MongoEngine in normal query construct (i.e I doubt that `Doc.objects(tags__in=["/^be/", "/^st/"]` will work)) but there is support for `__raw__` query (https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#raw-queries)

so the following should work

```
Inventory.objects(__raw__={"tags": { "$in":["/^be/", "/^st/"]}})
```